# Can we hide status bar and bottom navigation android phone bar

Tags: android

I tried this with immersive mode, its working properly, I have used

```
onWindowFocusChaned(Boolean hasfocus){
    return **View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY**

    }
```

and in on Resume()

```
{
    return **View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;**


    }
```

as it is working, but when I drag the status window, both status and navigation bar appears.
So Is there is any way without rooting we can hide it permanently.

Comment: See this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)